# Update map rotation with angles with orthographic projection

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, svg

I try to rotate a map using angles with orthographic projection. My aim is to center a map on a particular place without using drag'n drop or mouse move.

My map is created like that:

```
var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
     .scale(248)
     .clipAngle(90);

var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + height)
    .attr('width', mWidth)
    .attr('height', mWidth * height / width);

svg.append('rect')
   .attr('class', 'background')
   .attr('width', width)
   .attr('height', height);

var g = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'myid');

(...)
```

I saw this interesting article on the subject: http://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/. But this shows you how to using events.

How to do the same things using angle values?

Thanks for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [projection.rotate()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#rotate) should give you the desired rotation.

```
var lat = 54.6    // latitude 54.6S,
    lon = -22.3   // longitude 22.3E;

projection.rotate([lat, lon]);
```

This will rotate the projection to center on the coordinates supplied as an array.

Answer (score 1):

To center a map to a specific location under orthographic projection, you can use:

```
projection.rotate([-longitude, -latitude])
```

There is also interactive documentation about the rotation:
https://www.d3indepth.com/geographic/#rotate